# How to capture callback from failed validation in Joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, url-routing, hapi.js, joi

We're building a web service using Hapi. Our routes have some validation. I was wondering if it was possible to capture or override the default callback on failed validation, before or after hapi replies to the client.

my (non-working) code:

```
{
    method: 'GET',
    config: {
        tags: tags,
        validate: {
            params: {
                id: Joi.number()
                    .required()
                    .description('id of object you want to get'),
            },
            //Tried this, and it's not working:
            callback: function(err, value) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('need to catch errors here!');
                }
            }
        }
    },
    path: '/model/{id?}',
    handler: function(request, reply) {
        reply('Ok');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `failAction` attribute to add a callback:

```
validate: {
    params: {
        id: Joi.number()
            .required()
            .description('id of object you want to get'),
    },
    failAction: function (request, reply, source, error) {

        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

For more information see the [documentation](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#route-options):

> `failAction` - determines how to handle invalid requests. Allowed values are:
>
> - `'error'` - return a Bad Request (400) error response. This is the default value.
> - `'log'` - log the error but continue processing the request.
> - `'ignore'` - take no action.
> - a custom error handler function with the signature 'function(request, reply, source, error)` where:
>
>   - `request` - the request object.
>   - `reply` - the continuation reply interface.
>   - `source` - the source of the invalid field (e.g. `'path'`, `'query'`, `'payload'`).
>   - `error` - the error object prepared for the client response (including the validation function error under `error.data`).

Answer (score 0):

As I see in [API](http://hapijs.com/api), this maybe done using failAction:

> failAction - defines what to do when a response fails validation.
>   Options are:
>
> - error - return an Internal Server Error (500) error response. This is    the default value.
> - log - log the error but send the response.

```
failAction: function( source, error, next) {
    // your code
}
```