# JOI full path to key erroring out

Tags: node.js, schema, customization, joi

So Im writing a schema validation using JOI. https://github.com/hapijs/joi

I want to make a small change to the behavior of the error being thrown.

This is the error I got right now :

```
[
    {
        "name": "api_schema",
        "message": "\"architect\" with value \"Someasda2342432ssda\" fails to match the required pattern: /^[a-zA-Z_ ]{2,50}$/"
    }
]
```

But what I would like to receive is  :

```
[
        {
            "name": "api_schema",
            "message": "\"api_config.team_info.architect\" with value \"Someasda2342432ssda\" fails to match the required pattern: /^[a-zA-Z_ ]{2,50}$/"
        }
    ]
```

As you can see, I need that the error message indicates all the path to the failed key, not just its name. I know JOI has the ability to customize the error messages, and I can do that, but I dont find a way to get the value of the entire path to the key that failed.

Can someone advise?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`callback`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.3.0/API.md#joi) option. Something like this

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  a: Joi.string()
});

const object = { a: 123 };
const err = Joi.validate(object, schema, (err, value) => {
  // console.log('original error', err);
  err.newValidationError = 'new message ' + err.details[0].message;
  return err;
});

console.log(err);
```

If you are using with Hapi, you can also look at `failAction` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515005/how-to-capture-callback-from-failed-validation-in-joi)